# how passing request instance in methods work in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I know in order to make an instance in php, you have to use `new` keyword.

```
$object = new ClassName;
```

Now see the following code, which is so common in laravel

```
public function store(Request $request) {
   // some code inside store method
}
```

My question is when `$request` instance is created an filled by data? And how it's ok to pass it as an argument in the method?

Comment: If store is a controller method, then the `$request` is created and given to the method from the Service Container. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/container

Comment: Are you asking why the new keyword isn't used in the parameter part?

Comment: Its injected to the method. Its a built in function in laravel. It is not an arguments per say.

Comment: It might help you to research `Dependency Injection Containers (DIC)` and `Reflection`.

Answer (score 1):

The $request is created at the very beginning of the Laravel request/response cycle. Look in your ***index.php*** file and you will see something like this around line 52:

```
$response = $kernel->handle(
  $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);
```

If you follow the ***capture()*** function, you will end up in:

> /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php

which does this:

```
/**
 * Create a new Illuminate HTTP request from server variables.
 *
 * @return static
 */
public static function capture()
{
    static::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();

    return static::createFromBase(SymfonyRequest::createFromGlobals());
}
```

Laravel Request is built on top of SymfonyRequest, so if you follow **SymfonyRequest::createFromGlobals()**, it will take you to:

> /vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Request.php

In **createFromGlobals()** there is this line:

```
$request = self::createRequestFromFactory($_GET, $_POST, array(), $_COOKIE, $_FILES, $server);
```

And finally, if you go to **createRequestFromFactory()**, you will see:

```
private static function createRequestFromFactory(array $query = array(), array $request = array(), array $attributes = array(), array $cookies = array(), array $files = array(), array $server = array(), $content = null)
{
    if (self::$requestFactory) {
        $request = call_user_func(self::$requestFactory, $query, $request, $attributes, $cookies, $files, $server, $content);

        if (!$request instanceof self) {
            throw new \LogicException('The Request factory must return an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request.');
        }

        return $request;
    }

    return new static($query, $request, $attributes, $cookies, $files, $server, $content);
}
```

And this is where the Request is first made or passed back if already instantiated. So when you use:

```
 some_function(Request $request)
```

the "Request" just means the argument must be of type "Request" and the $request is the global $request variable that was created in ***index.php***.
Hope this helps some.

Comment: @eylay if this helped you out and solved the issue, please accept as answer and upvote.  :)